# How change the parameter from an inherited class that implements an interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have an interface and a class implementing the interface like this:

```
public interface DocumentDAO<T>{
    public long insert (T doc);
}

public class PostgreSQLDocumentDAO implements DocumentDAO<Document>{
    public long insert(Document doc){}
    protected void insertDocument(Document doc){}
}
```

I want to override the *insert* method of `PostgreSQLDocumentDAO` changing the parameter from *Document* to *Page*, where *Page* is a class that extends *Document*.

I want something like this:

```
public class PostgreSQLPageDAO extends PostgreSQLDocumentDAO{
    public long insert(Page doc){
        super.insertDocument(page);
        //specific implementation goes here
    }
}
```

How I can get this?

---

**UPDATE:** The code above isn't right because a class called `Inserter` uses the interface `DocumentDAO`. When it calls the *insert* method, even if is a *PostgreSQLPageDAO* object, it will call the insert method to insert *Document* because this method is inherited.

I want to do a way to when the `Inserter`class call the *insert* method, it uses the method that inserts the *page*. In this way, I think I need override the `insert (Document doc)` from `PostgreSQLDocumentDAO`.

Comment: What you are describing is how polymorphism works in Java.  What you are asking for is for the interface `DocumentDAO` to be able to choose a method based on a type it knows nothing about (i.e. `Page`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options here.

1. You can modify PostgreSQLDocumentDAO

Then you change it to

```
public class PostgreSQLDocumentDAO<D extends Document> implements DocumentDAO<D>
```

and

```
public class PostgreSQLPageDAO extends PostgreSQLDocumentDAO<Page>
```

2.You cannot modify PostgreSQLDocumentDAO

Then you need to overload and override the insert method in PostgreSQLPageDAO with:

```
// Override
@Override
public long insert(Document doc){
    if (!(doc instanceof Page))
         throw new IlegalArgumentException("insert only accepts Page");
    super.insert(doc);
}

// Overload
public long insert(Page page){
    super.insert(page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem.
Since `Page` is derived from `Document` you can simply pass a `Page` in place of a `Document`.

If you need special handling in the method of the derived class you could check if `Document` is `instanceof` `Page` and do what you need.

Of course the assumption is that you can't change the interfaces/classes

Comment: I edited my question and explained what is a problem. In "compilation" terms, it will work, but not in "logical" terms.